Algebraic Geometry: Some questions about a example of irreducible hypersurface and singular points
Some definitions:

Let $ M^{n} $ be a complex manifold of dimension $ n$. For an open subset $ U \subset M$, denote by $ \mathcal{O}(U) $ the ring of all holomorphic functions on $ U$. A hypersurface in $ M^{n} $ is a closed subset $ H $ that is locally the zero locus of a local holomorphic function. That is, for any $ p \in M$, there exist a neighborhood $ p \in U \subset M $ and a $ f \in \mathcal{O}(U) $ such that $ H \cap U=\{f=0\}$.
$f $ is called a local defining function of $ H$. A hypersurface $ H $ is said to be reducible if there are hypersurfaces $ H^{\prime}, H^{\prime \prime} $ in $ M $ such that $ H=H^{\prime} \cup H^{\prime \prime} $ and $ H^{\prime} \neq H, H^{\prime \prime} \neq H$. $H $ is said to be irreducible if it is not reducible. A point $ p \in H $ is called a regular point (or smooth point) of $ H$, if there exists a local defining function $ f $ of $ H $ near $ p $ so that $ d f(p) \neq 0$. In this case, by the implicit function theorem, $ U \cap H $ is a complex submanifold of codimension $1$ in a small neighborhood $ U $ of $p$. A point $ p \in H $ is called a singular point of $ H $ if it is not a regular point.

Example:

Consider the zero locus $ H $ of $ f(z)=z_{1}^{3}-z_{2}^{2} $ in $ \mathbb{C}^{2}$. It is an irreducible hypersurface (a curve in this case). Since $ d f=3 z_{1}^{2} d z_{1}-2 z_{2} d z_{2}$, $H $ is smooth everywhere except possibly at the origin. Since $[f]$ is irreducible in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{0}$ and $df(0)=0$, so $0$ is indeed a singular point of $H$. The map $ t \mapsto\left(t^{2}, t^{3}\right) $ from $ \mathbb{C}^{*} $ into $ H $ shows that $ H_{0}=H \backslash\{0\} $ is biholomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}^{*}$. (The origin is called a cusp of the curve $ H)$.

I have some questions about the example:

"It is an irreducible hypersurface (a curve in this case)". Why can we infer its irreducibility from being a complex curve? If we consider $g(z)=z_1z_2$, then the zero locus $Z$ of $g$ is a complex curve, but it is obviously reducible since $g(z)=g_1(z)g_2(z)$, where $g_1(z)=z_1$ and $g_2(z)=z_2$. We have $Z=Z_1\cup Z_2$ and $Z_1\neq Z\neq Z_2$, where $Z_1$, $Z_2$ are the zero locus of $g_1$ and $g_2$, respectively. So why it is irreducible?

"Since $[f]$ is irreducible in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{0}$". If I write $z_1^3-z_2^2=(z_1^{3/2}-z_2)(z_1^{3/2}+z_2)$, then both $z_1^{3/2}-z_2$ and $z_1^{3/2}+z_2$ are not units in the local ring since they are both zero at $z=0$. Is it unreasonable to do this? So what is the correct argument?

"Since $[f]$ is irreducible in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{0}$ and $df(0)=0$, so $0$ is indeed a singular point of $H$". The definition of singular point is that for all local defining function $ f $ of $ H $ near $ p $ we have $ d f(p) =0$. I can't see what this has to do with the irreducibility of $[f]$.


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The claim is not that we can infer irreducibility from its being a curve, the text just means it is irreducible and also a curve. It's irreducible because $z_1^3$ is not a square so $f(z)$ has no roots as a polynomial in $z_2$ (other arguments are also possible).

@QiaochuYuan I still don't quite understand. If $z_1=1$, then $f(1,z_2)=1-z_2^2$ has roots $z_2=\pm1$.

But $z_1$ isn't equal to $1$. The general claim is this: if $f(x, y) \in K[x, y]$ is a polynomial in two variables which is irreducible when considered as a one-variable polynomial in $K(x)[y]$, that is, when considered as a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $K(x)$, then it is irreducible in $K[x, y]$.

@QiaochuYuan I understand what you mean. For the second question, $\mathcal{O}{0}$ can be identified with the ring of all power series in $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ with positive radii of convergence and $f$ is irreducible as an element of the latter, so $[f]$ is irreducible in $\mathcal{O}{0}$. Is this idea correct?
